# How to let each mapper class to read the same one file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapper

In my hadoop job, except my input data files, I want each mapper class(the map method) to read a common file which I put in the hdfs. This file will be read into each mapper, and save the content in each mapper. So how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs there are different approaches:

- Read the file directly [from HDFS](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/hadoop-how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs) in each mapper. This is only recommended when the common file is realatively small.
- Use [CompositeInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/join/CompositeInputFormat.html) to read multiple files at once in each mapper at perform a so called map-side-join. Both files will be splitted and partitioned the same way.
- Add the file to a [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) during job setup. The file will be stored on every node an can accessed by all mappers.

Comment: hello, @harpun: I am very appreciate about your answer! But I still have some confused things to speack:1. I saw [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata)said,Distributed Cache tell the hdfs to send the copy file to all nodes.Does it mean each node will get a copy? By doing this, what's the difference between the option(1) and option(3)

Comment: @user2052141 yes, using the `DistributedCache` all nodes will get a copy of the files stored in this cache. Furthermore you need to specify the files, that are to be stored in the cache upon job setup, i.e. before actually running the job. In approach (1) you can access any file from HDFS at any stage of your job. Please note, that (1) is slower than (3) for common files.

Comment: hello, @harpun :thanks very much. another question is that do you know the difference between DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles and DistributedCache.getCacheFiles. I am programming to implement that, using:cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
            uris = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(job); However, cacheFiles to be null, but uris can point to the my specific file in the hdfs.

Comment: The `DistributedCache` behavior is not symmetrical in local mode vs. distributed mode. You need to use `DistributedCache.getCacheFiles()` in distributed mode. In your code, you can put a check: `if (getLocalCacheFiles())` returns `null` then use `getCacheFiles()` instead. Please post problems about the usage of `DistributedCache` as a new question along with your code, because they're out of scope of your initial question. Try searching google and SO first, they're many related questions.